# Java (via jdbc) no longer getting through to Postgres DB on LAN after Windows Update

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, windows-update

I have a large LAN with multiple database servers and clients. I just installed the latest Windows updates (2020-09 Cumulative Updates) on one of the clients, and now our java software can no longer connect to the database. I did a test run right before executing the update, and it worked as expected. Then after the update I now receive the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 8 more
```

I'm able to use psql at the command line to connect from the client to the server just fine. The other clients on the LAN that have not been updated are all working correctly. I've tried adding firewall outbound rules for java on the client and inbound rules on the server (this is not necessary for our existing configuration, but figured I'd give it a shot). I also tried adding outbound and inbound rules for postgres on the client. I also attempted to update our jdbc driver (currently running postgresql-8.3-604.jdbc3 and tried updating to postgresql-42.2.16.jre7) this did not fix it either.

Edit: I have also tried completely turning off the firewall on both the server and the client, and I still receive the above error.

Comment: "*connect timed out*" typically means that a firewall blocked the connection. But regardless of that error, you should be using that ancient driver version 8.3.x anymore. And are you really still using Java 7?

Comment: yes, and I know we need to update. But that is a conversation for another day. I tried adding firewall rules for both java and postgres, and neither worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: By default PostgreSQL uses port 5432.  I agree that this really looks like a firewall issue of some sort.  In a command line can you do a `telnet <database host or ip> 5432`?  You may need to [enable telnet for Windows](https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-enable-telnet).  If the command just hangs then don't have the ability to connect, completely outside of your Java program.

Comment: @stdunbar, I'm able to connect to the port via psql at the command line from the client to the host. So the host is accepting connections on the port 5432. Not to mention all the other machines on the LAN that are actively connecting to the same server without issue. It seems to me that the issue is the connection specifically coming from the java application on the machine that had the new windows update installed on it. I tried a variety of different firewall settings involving java .exes to try to get it go through and no luck so far.